# Minify Html , Js , Css and Php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, minify

Im looking for the better way to minify those files but im still noob , currently im working  with atom editor so im using a plugin called atom-minify whichs minify my css and js but not the html , after this i have to compress the proyecto to upload to the server or it is not necesary ?

Comment: Use http://minifier.org/ I am using it for my website,

Comment: Its not necessary to minify the codes. It just reduces the filesize which hence increases the page loading speed. Minifying is not advised until you put your code into production.

Comment: you can use https://pakd.io  they merge your css and js files as well

Answer (score 0):

Probably best is to use Gulp/ Grunt for such a thing. [Here is how to set it up Grunt](http://ryanchristiani.com/getting-started-with-grunt-and-sass/).

And then use plugin such as [Grunt-minified](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-minified) to do your minifications(not sure if minifications is a real word but... :D).

In any case, its better if you use Grunt/ Gulp in your projects as they help you with:

1) Work in as small chunks of CSS and JavaScript as makes sense to you, then concatenate them together for the production website.

2) Compress your CSS and minify your JavaScript to make their file sizes as small as possible for your production website.

3) Optimize your images to reduce their file size without affecting quality.

4) Use Sass for CSS authoring because of all the useful abstraction it allows.